# C++ matrix class operator using std::common_type_t and implementation of complex number

Tags: c++, matrix, type-conversion, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

I am writing a matrix class myself and I am trying to make it as "generic" as possible, i.e., I want a `matrix<int> + matrix<double>` to be able to yield `matrix<double>`, `matrix<double> * matrix<int>` able to yield `matrix<double>`.

So in my `operator+`, my in-class declaration is

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    ......
    template <typename TT> Matrix operator+(const Matrix<TT>&);
    ......
private:
    ......
}
```

and the definition is

```
template<typename T, typename TT>
Matrix<T> Matrix<TT>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &M)
{
    using C = std::common_type_t<T, TT>;
    Matrix<C> temp(_rows, _cols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        temp.mtx[i] = mtx[i] + M.mtx[i];
    return temp;
}
```

However, the compiler complains that

> template argument list must match the parameter list

I don't know where is wrong. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

As for the implementation of complex number. There are some operations that are incompatible with std::complex, such as max, min, operator<, etc. The solution I came up with is I wrote a new matrix class for complex matrix, but this is stupid. Is there an easy way around this?

======================================================================

My constructor:

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() { allocate(0.0); }    // this is a private function allocating memory
```

the `allocate` member

```
template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::allocate(T val)
{
    mtx = new T [_rows * _cols];
    if(val) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _rows * _cols; ++i)
            mtx[i] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one you are referring to?

Comment: @Evg Right right. I just added it.

Comment: Shouldn't `matrix<int> + matrix<double>` and `matrix<double> + matrix<int>` both yield `matrix<double>`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix two templates into one. Try this:

```
template<typename TT>
template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<TT>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &M)
{
    using C = std::common_type_t<T, TT>;
    Matrix<C> temp(_rows, _cols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
        temp.mtx[i] = mtx[i] + M.mtx[i];
    return temp;
}
```

However, the return type is `Matrix<T>` and you return `Matrix<C>`. So I suggest you write it like this (don't forget to adjust the declaration accordingly):

```
template<typename TT>
template<typename T, typename C = std::common_type_t<T, TT>> // pseudocode, see below
Matrix<C> Matrix<TT>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &M) const
{
    Matrix<C> temp(...);
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

Complete example:

```
template<class T>
struct Matrix
{
    template<class S, class C = std::common_type_t<T, S>>
    Matrix<C> operator+(const Matrix<S>&) const;
};

template<class T>
template<class S, class C>
Matrix<C> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<S>&) const
{ ... }
```

Since C++14 you can use `auto` return type:

```
template<class T>
struct Matrix
{
    template<class S>
    auto operator+(const Matrix<S>&) const
    {
        using C = std::common_type_t<T, S>; 
        Matrix<C> tmp(...);
        ...
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

As to your second question, it is not clear what the problem is. Note that template member functions are not instantiated unless they are used. So you can have member functions that employ, e.g., `operator<`, just don't use them with complex matrices.

> The operator> here is incompatible with std::complex. I don't know how to go around it if I use complex matrix.

It is fine to have this member in a template class. Just don't use it with complex matrices. However, I suggest you [make it a free function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLDT1lDOsb4). Then you won't have this concern altogether.

Comment: now it says _no instance of overloaded function matches the specified type_

Comment: @SJH, please include both declaration and definition into your question, i.e. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you mean the declaration/definition for which one? The complex matrix?

Comment: @SJH, I mean the one for which you get an error. I included a complete example in my updated answer, take a look.

Comment: This implementation leads to another series of issues. First, I can't access the private member of that **temp** matrix. Second, my constructor can't convert `int` to `std::common_type<double, int>`. I'll just attach my construtor above. Please take a look.

Comment: @SJH, do you really need to access private members? How can it be that to form a sum of matrices one needs to access their internals? Maybe you should rethink your interface? If you really need private access, add `template<class> friend struct Matrix;` to friend all matices.

Comment: It's ok if I don't access those private members. That's fine. But still, due to this `common_type`, there are many other problems, one of which is what I just mentioned.

Comment: @SJH, I don't see where `int` to `std::common_type<>` conversion happens exactly. Probably you should redesign your constructors.

Comment: I update my post with one of my private member `allocate`, I think that's where the conversion happens. Could you take a look?

Comment: It just came to me: would it be helpful to add some type-conversion members in my class to avoid this `common_type`?

Comment: @SJH, I doubt it. However, `std::common_type` is not a proper type in the general case. The correct type is given by `decltype(std::declval + std::declval)` and `decltype(std::declval * std::declval)`.